# Using images in Matlab GUI

Tags: image, user-interface, matlab, image-processing

I'm working on a small image processing project in MATLAB. I have worked with MATLAB before, but never created a GUI. The GUI I want to create could be pretty advanced, so I need some hints on how to get started.

The purpose of the GUI would be to load an image and have it shown to the user. The user then has to click on two points in the image, of which the coordinates are stored (in pixels) in a variable. If possible, a colored dot is shown where the user has clicked. After the user finished with the current image, he can load a next one.

I have some experience with Java, and I think this wouldn't be too hard in Swing. But MATLAB seems like not having the purpose of creating such an advanced GUI. However, the whole project until now is in MATLAB, so it would be nice if I could manage to do it. Any help? Hints? Things I should look at?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can call Java from Matlab, so if you're comfortable with Swing, why not do it there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a very complex task to be done in MATLAB.

For simple instructions about adding a picture to a GUI, take a look at this post:
http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2007/10/16/matlab-basics-setting-a-background-image-for-a-gui/

For instructions on various interactions between GUI axes and the mouse pointer, check this video (keep in mind that your picture in the GUI lies within normal MATLAB axes):
http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/05/27/advanced-matlab-capture-mouse-movement/

In general, Doug's tutorial videos are great for MATLAB beginners, and I'd advise you to take a look at more of them.

Comment: Now moved to here, http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2008/05/27/advanced-matlab-capture-mouse-movement/